# BPL en Delphi con FLAG "Link With Runtime Link Package" en False

Tags: delphi

Tengo un proyecto que usa una BPL desarrollada por mi sobre Delphi Rio o Delphi Tokyo.

Con el FLAG "Link With Runtime Link Package" en TRUE el proyecto compila, pero con el Flag en FALSE no compila porque no encuentra las unidades de la BPL.

Al compilar con el Flag en False, pretendo que el ejecutable incluya las BPL's, si no debo distribuir las BPL's propias y de Delphi con el ejecutable.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tu proyecto compile sin utilizar la BPL en tiempo de corrida, debes incluir la ruta dónde tienes las unidades dentro del *library path*, para que el compilador sea capaz de encontrarlas y enlazarlas dentro de tu ejecutable.

Al compilador puedes darle:

- Los fuentes (.pas) de las unidades o
- DCU's de las unidades, siempre que sean compatibles con la versión del compilador.

Para ello, puedes hacerlo a nivel global (es lo más común si el BPL contiene componentes propios).

En el menú, *Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library > Library path* incluye la ruta de la carpeta donde tengas los archivos mencionados.

También puedes hacerlo dentro de las opciones del proyecto, si no quieres que estas unidades estén disponibles para otros proyectos.

Comment: jachguate. la situación es que debo distribuir los archivos DCP y BPL a otros integrantes del equipo. Y la idea es no entregar fuentes ni DCU.
Entiendo que el "linkage" en un solo ejecutable lo realiza Delphi con base en los DCP y los BPL.

Comment: Hasta donde recuerdo, esto no es posible. Técnicamente, el dcp tiene dentro los dcu's, pero francamente nunca lo he intentado, generalmente, incluso con componentes de terceros, se dispone, al menos de los dcu's, dfm's y otros artefactos necesarios para la compilación sin paquetes en tiempo de corrida.

Comment: [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39220963/255257) en StackOverflow en Inglés va en la misma dirección.

Comment: Y este [post](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2018/08/30/on-the-delphi-dcp-files/) en el blog de Serg, dice que los dcp's son necesarios solo para compilar paquetes interdependientes, pero no para construir la aplicación final, que si requiere los dcu's. ¿Por qué no quieres distribuir los dcu's?

Comment: Una de las razones es la administración de los DCU. En unos pocos BPL o DCP, se podría tener un mejor control de versiones. 
Así evitaremos que alguno de los integrantes del equipo llegue a tener dcu's de versiones diferentes.

Comment: Puedes colocar los DCU's dentro del control de versiones, es uno de los casos donde yo personalmente lo hago, y que la persona que tiene los fuentes, sea el encargado de hacer commit de los DCU's solo cuando haya algún cambio. El resto del equipo va a tener los DCU's correctos en cada revisión, sin mezclar versiones. Otra posible solución es que el resto del equipo compile usando runtime packages en true, y que haya un equipo más reducido y experimentado, con acceso a los fuentes o a los dcu's que sea el que hace los builds de la versión entregable, sin runtime packages.

Comment: Gracias jachguate.
De todas formas me queda la inquietud de que RAD Studio ofrezca la posibilidad de generar en el ejecutable el contenido de las BPL y que se deba configurar el path con la ubicación de los DCU o incluso de los DFM.

Comment: Es justo lo que digo en mi respuesta, configura el _path_ con los dcu's. El BPL no es necesario para compilar. El BPL lo utiliza el propio IDE para _crear_ los componentes en tiempo de diseño (que para el IDE es tiempo de corrida). Puede ser algo confuso al inicio.

Comment: jachguate, encontré el artículo "http://programandonet.com/questions/47440/como-dividir-un-proyecto-delphi-en-bpls-correctamente" y menciona lo siguiente:
<<<<<<<
Los paquetes se componen de dos partes: el bpl y el dcp. El dcp es como los archivos dcu generados cuando compila un archivo de unidad normal, excepto que contiene un montón de unidades en él. Usar una clase compilada en bpl es tan simple como agregar el dcp a la lista de paquetes del proyecto y luego agregar una unidad a una cláusula de uso de una de las unidades del proyecto.
>>>>>>>

Comment: Voy a intentar diferentes opciones de configuración a fin de obtener el resultado. Y comentaré el resultado. 
La situación es que no he podido abrir el caso con Embarcadero porque la página de soporte tiene problemas; pienso que también puede ser un bug de RAD Studio.

Comment: No tengo Delphi a mano ahora, pero también haré un par de pruebas luego de tu último comentario y comento después.

Comment: Al fin pude abrir el caso con IDERA y en resumen dicen lo que ya se planteó:
<<<<<<<
 If you also want your code to be available so that it can be statically linked into an application (i.e. Link with runtime packages set to False) then you will need to make the DCU files available to your developers. The directory containing the DCU files needs to be added to the Library Path so that the compiler and linker can find them.

Comment: Gracias por la retroalimentación, GBM. El otro día estuve viendo las opciones del proyecto y supuse que no había forma de hacerlo, pero olvidé venir a comentarlo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Con el FLAG `"Link With Runtime Link Package"` en TRUE, debes tener los BPL's/DCP's para poder compilar.

Con el FLAG `"Link With Runtime Link Package"` en FALSE, debes tener los PAS's/DCU's de las versiones correctas para compilar.

No puedes mezclar ambas opciones.

Un fichero BPL es el equivalente a una DLL o un ejecutable. Lo que pretendes hacer es como si desde un ejecutable quisieras incluir el contenido de otro ejecutable. No puedes hacerlo, porque ya ha sido compilado y linkado.

Si deseas generar un ejecutable con `"Link With Runtime Link Package"` en FALSE, necesitas tener los fuentes o los DCU's para que el compilador pueda resolver referencias y compilar y linkar el proyecto.

Comment: Gracias Germán.
Y cuál es el papel de los DCP?

Comment: @GBM En ejecución sólo necesitas los BPL's, los DCP's los necesitas para trabajar desde el IDE.
Cuando instalar una aplicación en un cliente sñolo distribuyes los BPL's, el programador que la está realizando necesita los DCP's para trabajar con Delphi y esos componentes (o código).